# PDF official paper format

Tags: c#, winforms

I did generate a pdf file from jpg images. But the jpg images have the size of an official paper. When I open the pdf, the image is too big. I need that the pdf document is in official paper size. Any solution? (panel1 has the size of offical paper. I need that this size is equal of offical paper's size)

```
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF Files|*.pdf";
        string fileName = string.Empty;
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "name.pdf";
        btnGerarPDF.Visible = false;
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(panel1.ClientSize.Width,
                                               panel1.ClientSize.Height))
        {
            panel1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, panel1.ClientRectangle);
            bitmap.Save("C:\\" + (nPaginasPDF + 1) + ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
        }

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            fileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            Document doc = new Document();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open();

            for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < nPaginasPDF+1; iCnt++)
            {
                iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C:\\" + (iCnt + 1) + ".bmp");
                image1.ScalePercent(75f);
                doc.NewPage();
                doc.Add(image1);
            }

            doc.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the pagesize when you create the document:

`Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);`

Comment: I know..but I need an Idea for my problem: I need print in offical paper size and need a backup from this document. Then I try to create a pdf file as backup. But it's big than pdf document..

Comment: I solved my problem change the size of my image, but I will mark as right answer because has no other possible solution. PDF doesn't accept to be created with official paper size.